# Make table smaller

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have this table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Thin Rod Simulation Results for 2 Material Forwards Euler}
\label{tbl:2}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXX}
 \toprule
  & x & T = 0.01 & T = 0.015 & T = 0.02 \\
 \midrule
 c2 = 1 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.243 & 0.232 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.685 & 0.652 & 0.621 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.897 & 0.854 & 0.813 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.825 & 0.785 & 0.748 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.490 & 0.467 & 0.444 \\
 \midrule
 c2 = 5 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.242 & 0.228 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.680 & 0.635 & 0.585 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.806 & 0.699 & 0.604 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.624 & 0.535 & 0.460 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.351 & 0.298 & 0.255 \\
\midrule
 c2 = 10 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.240 & 0.221 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.667 & 0.596 & 0.510 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.610 & 0.383 & 0.185 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.472 & 0.324 & 0.192 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.262 & 0.186 & 0.117 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But the problem is that it is too big and I need it **much** smaller. Something like this:

[image]

I got that image I screenshoting the original table and making it smaller. But that's sort of cheating. So how can I make it really small like I have in the image? I tried `0.5\textwidth`, but that doesn't look good. Maybe multirow for first column?

Comment: Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO2PA.png

Comment: How much smaller and what should be smaller? The vertical distance between rows? The font size...? And what do you want to use `\multirow` for?

Comment: Do you want to vertically center the "c=..." with respect to the five rows that it corresponds to? If you want to keep it vertically aligned with "1/11" there is no need fow `\multirow`.

Comment: why are you forcing the table to be taller with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` and wider with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` if you want it smaller?

Comment: that is, simply removing those is an answer as Zarko showed, but I wonder what was the intention, perhaps there is some other way to achieve whatever these were intended to do, presumably they were added for a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two versions of your table: I have used  a regular `tabular` since there is no need for automatic linebreaks in table columns. In order to improve the alignment of the numbers, I have used `siunitx`. In the second example, I have additionally reduced the font size to `\small` and the `\arraystretch` to `1`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.65in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Thin Rod Simulation Results for 2 Material Forwards Euler}
\label{tbl:2}
 \begin{tabular}{lcc*{3}{S[table-format=1.3]}}
 \toprule
  & x & {T = 0.01} & {T = 0.015} & {T = 0.02} \\
 \midrule
 c2 = 1 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.243 & 0.232 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.685 & 0.652 & 0.621 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.897 & 0.854 & 0.813 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.825 & 0.785 & 0.748 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.490 & 0.467 & 0.444 \\
 \midrule
 c2 = 5 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.242 & 0.228 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.680 & 0.635 & 0.585 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.806 & 0.699 & 0.604 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.624 & 0.535 & 0.460 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.351 & 0.298 & 0.255 \\
\midrule
 c2 = 10 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.240 & 0.221 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.667 & 0.596 & 0.510 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.610 & 0.383 & 0.185 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.472 & 0.324 & 0.192 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.262 & 0.186 & 0.117 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\small
\caption{Thin Rod Simulation Results for 2 Material Forwards Euler}
\label{tbl:2}
 \begin{tabular}{lcc*{3}{S[table-format=1.3]}}
 \toprule
  & x & {T = 0.01} & {T = 0.015} & {T = 0.02} \\
 \midrule
 c2 = 1 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.243 & 0.232 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.685 & 0.652 & 0.621 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.897 & 0.854 & 0.813 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.825 & 0.785 & 0.748 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.490 & 0.467 & 0.444 \\
 \midrule
 c2 = 5 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.242 & 0.228 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.680 & 0.635 & 0.585 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.806 & 0.699 & 0.604 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.624 & 0.535 & 0.460 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.351 & 0.298 & 0.255 \\
\midrule
 c2 = 10 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.240 & 0.221 \\
 & 3/11 & 0.667 & 0.596 & 0.510 \\
 & 5/11 & 0.610 & 0.383 & 0.185 \\
 & 7/11 & 0.472 & 0.324 & 0.192 \\
 & 9/11 & 0.262 & 0.186 & 0.117 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `tabularx` if you have a regular tabular that would otherwise be wider than the textwidth. Use it only if that `tabular` contains a column with text, not with numbers. Use the `X` type column for columns in which you want to allow linebreaks to make the overall table narrower. Your table is already narrower than the textwidth and you aparantly don't want the table to be as wide as the textwidth --> no need for `tabularx` for this spwcific table.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness ... using standard `c` columns and `tabular` table environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.65in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
%\usepackage{float}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Thin Rod Simulation Results for 2 Material Forwards Euler}
\label{tbl:2}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \toprule
        & \multirow{2.4}{*}{x}
                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{T} \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
        &       & 0.01  & 0.015 & 0.02  \\
    \midrule
 c2 = 1 & 1/11  & 0.255 & 0.243 & 0.232 \\
        & 3/11  & 0.685 & 0.652 & 0.621 \\
        & 5/11  & 0.897 & 0.854 & 0.813 \\
        & 7/11  & 0.825 & 0.785 & 0.748 \\
        & 9/11  & 0.490 & 0.467 & 0.444 \\
    \midrule
 c2 = 5 & 1/11  & 0.255 & 0.242 & 0.228 \\
        & 3/11  & 0.680 & 0.635 & 0.585 \\
        & 5/11  & 0.806 & 0.699 & 0.604 \\
        & 7/11  & 0.624 & 0.535 & 0.460 \\
        & 9/11  & 0.351 & 0.298 & 0.255 \\
    \midrule
 c2 = 10 & 1/11 & 0.255 & 0.240 & 0.221 \\
         & 3/11 & 0.667 & 0.596 & 0.510 \\
         & 5/11 & 0.610 & 0.383 & 0.185 \\
         & 7/11 & 0.472 & 0.324 & 0.192 \\
         & 9/11 & 0.262 & 0.186 & 0.117 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @dave, only if you have installed old `multirow` package. Try to update your LaTeX instalation. With old `multirow` package you can write `\multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{x}`.